# DateTime.Parse DD/MM/YYYY 24 Hour Clock

Tags: .net, datetime

DateTime.Parse fails on

```
 15/08/2000 16:58
```

Any thoughts?

I need to parse dates and get some international.

DD/MM/YYYY will not flop to 24 hour clock

MM/DD/YYYY will accept 24 hour clock

15/08/2000 4:58 PM will parse

From the Kibbee answer I looked at using other cultures. 
I use Regex to determine if it is dd/MM and if so use culture fr-FR.

Comment: Are you specifying the correct culture when calling parse?

Comment: My current culture is en-US.  Like I said some are international.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
                                 "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
                                 new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 13):

You should probably be using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to parse the date if you know the exact format that you expect the date to be in.  For your purposes, the following will probably work.

```
string dateString, format;  
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

dateString = "15/08/2000 16:58"
format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Change to above. Changed hh to HH because HH signifies 24 hour time. If you don't use a leading zero, then simply use H.  For more information on creating format strings [see this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

Also from the linked MSDN article, it appears as though the format "g" should work.

```
dateString = "15/06/2008 08:30";
format = "g";
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Comment: Problem is that I do NOT know the format.  I am literally parsing millions of dates from emails.  Let me test out your answer.

Comment: If you don't know they format, you're going to have problems with accuracy, as 10/11/2008 could either mean October 11, 2008 or November 10, 2008.  Both date formats are quite popular.

Comment: But I can live with inaccurate but consistent.  This is for email threading.  Would prefer accurate.

Comment: The connection to my server went down so I cannot test out until tomorrow but if it works will mark as answer.

Comment: I went to your other posts and gave two +1 so you got the points of an answer.